# Android N: ProgressDialog and AlertDialog display issue

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, progressdialog, android-7.0-nougat

**Problem**:

I am using `AlertDialog` and `ProgressDialog` at multiple places in the app. They are displaying fine with Android versions below Android N Preview. However when I tested them with Android N Preview (NDP3 on Nexus 5X), the translucent background doesn't seem to cover the whole screen.

*Translucent background of dialog not covering the whole screen in Android N:*
[image]

This is how I'm creating the dialog in the activity:

```
public static void showDialog(final Activity activity, final String title, final String message, final String positiveButtonText, final String negativeButtonText, final DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveButtonListener, final DialogInterface.OnClickListener negativeButtonListener, final Boolean cancellable) {
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            alert.setTitle(title);
            alert.setMessage(message);
            alert.setPositiveButton(positiveButtonText != null ? positiveButtonText : activity.getString(R.string.button_text_ok), positiveButtonListener);
            alert.setNegativeButton(negativeButtonText != null ? negativeButtonText : activity.getString(R.string.button_text_cancel), negativeButtonListener);

            if (cancellable != null) {
                alert.setCancelable(cancellable);
            } else {
                alert.setCancelable(false);
            }

            //creating an alert dialog from our builder.
            alertDialog = alert.create();
            if (!activity.isFinishing() && alertDialog != null) {
                alertDialog.show();
                alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, android.R.color.black));
                alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, android.R.color.black));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the activity theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
</style>

<!-- Base application theme. Include the items here which are common to all version. -->
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--Customize Action Bar-->
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.TradeRev.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.TradeRev.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/light_green</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/green_title_bar</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/button_back_up_navigation</item>

    <!-- Title Text Color -->
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.Widget.TextView</item>
</style>
```

**Question**:

Is this a issue with Android N or has something changed in the API's which we need to incorporate for Android N and above?

Comment: Other than not using a `DialogFragment` for handling configuration changes, your code would seem to be OK, relative to this problem. Are you doing anything dialog-related int the theme used by this activity?

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the comment. The app is only portrait for now but anyways should use `DialogFragment`. Most of the stuff in the theme is with ActionBar and colour etc. I've included it in the question for your kind reference.

Comment: I do not see anything in that theme that strikes me as the source of your problem. That being said, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Dialogs/DialogFragment) of mine behaves normally on a Nexus 6 and a Nexus 9, each running NDP3.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried your project. Same issue. I'm using Nexus 5X. Maybe its something device specific. Here is the snapshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25769338/Screenshot_20160526-122908.png

Comment: If you ran that project unmodified, then my guess is that it is device-specific. It's odd that this particular effect would be device-specific, but ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. I do not have NDP3 loaded on a 5X, so I cannot confirm the behavior. I recommend that you file a bug report on this, whether using my sample project or one of your own. If you use mine, and you think of it, post the link here in a comment, and I can post the screenshots coming from a Nexus 6 and Nexus 9 for comparison.

Comment: This is a KI for N DP. See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205765

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in N DP. See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205765

It is a platform issue. You do not need to work around this in your app.

Comment: If possible, could you please re-open that issue? It is marked as released at the moment, which means that it might not get addressed. Thanks!

Comment: OP needs to file a new issue at https://developer.android.com/preview/bug and include relevant sample project, OS version, etc.